# Convert 'Web Tab' to 'Visualforce' tab via tabs in Metadata API error

Tags: metadata-api, error, metadata, tab

I have a very simple tab that goes to a url. However I want to replace the tab with a Visualforce page override. I was hoping to convert the old 'Web Tab' into a 'Visualforce Tab' it rather than delete and create a new one, but I'm having difficulties and I'm getting the following error:

> Result: [OPERATION FAILED]: MySource: field integrity exception: unknown (url cannot be specified on Apex Page custom tab)

Old tab

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomTab xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <frameHeight>600</frameHeight>
    <hasSidebar>true</hasSidebar>
    <label>MySource</label>
    <mobileReady>true</mobileReady>
    <motif>Custom42: Treasure chest</motif>
    <url>http://www.google.com/</url>
    <urlEncodingKey>UTF-8</urlEncodingKey>
</CustomTab>
```

New tab

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomTab xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <label>MySource</label>
    <mobileReady>false</mobileReady>
    <motif>Custom51: Apple</motif>
    <page>mySourceRedirect</page>
</CustomTab>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to delete the tab and recreate it. You can't convert any type of tab to any other type of tab. Once the tab's type is determined, it is read-only and cannot be modified.